# Mass distribution driven by gravitational field

Tags: gravity

In a gravitational field, should the mass distributions always behave well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  There are numerous well-known mass distributions that start out non-singular, and which collapse to form a black-hole after a finite amount of time.

Black hole solutions, however, have a region of infinite density and infinite spacetime curvature, so they are not at all well-behaved in any ordinary sense.

Comment: @Jerry Schirmer: Is the converse true ? If there is a point where the distribution is not well behaved then there should be a black hole.

Comment: No.  All sorts of different singularities are possible.

Comment: @Jerry Schirmer: please give some examples

Comment: In another thread, you're hostile to a discussion that uses technical math.  Discussing Taub-NUT singularities and cosmological singularities without technical math is somewhat pointless.  But there are definitely singular spacetimes that aren't black hole solutions, irrepsective of anything else.

Comment: @Jerry Schirmer: The very idea of me asking the question is to know the mathematical nature of gravitational field.My lack of terminology in Physics had prompted me to ask for explanation and not the math. What is the mathematical nature of these 'Taub-NUT' and 'cosmological' singularities ? Please note that my interest is in the nature rather than whether they are in space or time or mass distribution or anything else.

Comment: I would suggest picking up Bernard Schutz's "a first course in general relativity".  Any answer I give will just generate more questions.  To have any satisfactory answer to this broad of a question will require more background than is practical here.